# Notation for referring to a Ruby nested class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if there is any special notation or common practice when it comes to referring (outside of actual code, either in comments, source control commit messages, or documentation) to nested classes in Ruby/Rails. I ask because in the application there is this code:

```
class Reporting::Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Reporting module is defined outside this file.
  ...
  class Data < HashWithIndifferentAccess
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

And my commit message reads:

> Modifies [...] in the Data class within Reporting::Search, [...]"

Is there a more standard way to phrase this? Something like `Reporting::Search::Data` or `Reporting::Search.Data`?

Comment: Note: this is a nested constant, not a nested class. Ruby doesn't have nested classes like [Beta](http://daimi.au.dk/~beta/) has.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, could you expand on that? It certainly looks like that is a nested class, as it is defined with the keyword `class`, it appears to subclass `HashWithIndifferentAccess` (that's where it gets most of its behavior), and several separate instances of it are defined and used within the `Reporting::Search` class.

Comment: Yes, it is a class, and yes the constant `Data` is nested inside the class `Reporting::Search`, however that relationship is only between the constant `Data` and `Reporting::Search`, there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever between the class which the constant `Data` points to and the class which the constant `Data` is defined in. The only class that `Data` has a relationship with is `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. You can assign the class to a different constant defined in a different class and exactly none of the behavior would change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reporting::Search::Data` is correct. Your hierarchy there is analogous to:

```
module Reporting
  class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
    class Data <HashWithIndifferentAccess; end
  end
end
```

And in fact, this form is preferred, since it will define the `Reporting` module if it is not already defined, while the `Reporting::Search` form will throw an exception.